# Weird behaviour of Ruby multithreading

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm trying to understand Ruby multithreading, and it seems just chaotic. Here's a couple examples I tried:

1. Thread never gets executed and program ends

```rb
Thread.new do
  puts "thread"
end

puts "main"
```

2. Thread is executed but never terminates

```rb
thread = Thread.new do
  puts "thread"
end

sleep while thread.alive?

puts "main"
```

3. Everything unexpectedly works as expected:

```rb
thread = Thread.new do
  puts "thread"
end

puts thread.status while thread.alive?

puts "main"
```

What in Matz' name is going on here?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Thread never gets executed and program ends

```
Thread.new do
  puts "thread"
end

puts "main"
```

Threads run in parallel. The main Ruby process will not automatically wait until all threads are completed before exiting.

What you're missing is [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Thread.html#method-i-join). This waits until the thread is done.

```
thread = Thread.new do
  puts "thread"
end

puts "main"

thread.join
```

---

> Thread is executed but never terminates

```
thread = Thread.new do
  puts "thread"
end

sleep while thread.alive?

puts "main"
```

[`sleep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sleep) with no arguments sleeps forever. Give it a short time to sleep and it works.

```
thread = Thread.new do
  puts "thread"
end

sleep(0.1) while thread.alive?

puts "main"
```

---

> Everything unexpectedly works as expected:

```
thread = Thread.new do
  puts "thread"
end

puts thread.status while thread.alive?

puts "main"
```

Now that you're not sleeping forever, it works as expected.

Comment: When I run the first example, the program clearly exits before executing the thread:
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/PySjKDUxRS8vtVwhJZ9LQaGgtKRYQakELKrElZqXwsUFEcpNzMxT@v8fAA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: @Sinthorion No worries.